# AWS API Gateway Header and Body Mappings in Integration Response

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to properly setup Body Mapping and Header Mapping in the Integration Response for an API Gateway endpoint.

In our Lambda we have

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    context.succeed(output);
} else if (response.statusCode == 206) {
    var paginationObject = {
        errorType : "PartialContent",
        errorCode : 206,
        detailedMessage : "PartialContent Returned",
        stackTrace : [],
        data : {
               output
        }
    };

    context.fail(JSON.stringify(paginationObject));
}
```

I then handle fetching this in the Integration Response using a Lambda Error Regex of **.*PartialContent.*** and have my Body Mapping Template as

```
#set($allParams = $input.params())
#set($body = $util.parseJson($input.json('$.errorMessage')))

$body
```

This gives me the correct HTTP status code and JSON output, but it has too much data in the body. The response looks like:

```
{
  "errorType":"PartialContent",
  "errorCode":206,
  "detailedMessage":"PartialContent Returned",
  "stackTrace":[],
  "data":{
    "output":{
      "status":206,
      "bodyJson":[{"call_date":"2017-08-19 18:17:21"}],
      "headers":{"date":"Thu, 02 Nov 2017 18:36:52 GMT",
                 "server":"Apache",
                 "x-pagination-page-size":10}
    }
  }
}
```

I want the headers to actually appear as headers in the response, and I want the body to just be the content inside of bodyJson

I've tried to change the body mapping template to use **$body.data.output.bodyJson**, but when I do that the body is completely empty. I've also got the headers set in the Header Mappers, trying both **integration.response.body.headers.x-pagination-page-size** and **integration.response.header.x-pagination-page-size** but both times the header is blank, even though I can see the proper values in the JSON output.

How do I get just the bodyJson element to be output as the body of the response? And how do I properly get the headers mapped?

Comment: $body.data.output.bodyJson is an array, depending on what is the usecase, you can either iterate over all the maps in bodyJson array and merge them(or return the first map in the array if that is the case); or you can do {body: $body.data.output.bodyJson}; the latter will return map like {"body": [{"call_date":"2017-08-19 18:17:21"}]}

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use **Lambda Error Regex** in Integration Response?
 For example:

> .*"status":400.*

**body mapping templetes**:

```
#set ($errorMessageObj = $util.parseJson($input.path('$.errorMessage')))
{
  "status" : "$errorMessageObj.status",
  "errorType" : "$errorMessageObj.errorType",
  "message" : "$errorMessageObj.errorMessage"
}
```

I created an **error function** in my **Lamda**:

```
function error(status, errorType, errorMessage, callback){
    callback(JSON.stringify({
        status: status,
        errorType: errorType,
        errorMessage: errorMessage
    }));
}
```

usage:

```
error(404, "Not Found", "Resource is not found", callback);
```