# AWS API Gateway Method Response Status

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've seen other responses for similar questions but am horribly stuck.

Trying to set a HTTP response in API Gateway (APIGW) from a lambda function.

I get the below from hitting the APIGW end-point:

```
{"code":404,"body":"No products found.","statusCode":0,"successful":false}
```

When I try to map this to a 404 from APIGW, it never catches despite having tried just about every permutation of the response.  The latest one I have in there was (in integration response):

```
Lambda regex: .*"404".*
Body mapping: $input.path('$')
```

Used a string in regex as the MIME type isn't being set to json even though the response looks like it.  Have tried all sorts of variants for the body mapping.

This seems to work flawlessly for most other people but no dice; any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is my example https://stackoverflow.com/a/47105287/6108211

Answer (score 0):

Looks like our fancy lambda is the issue; APIGW is looking for a defined response structure (errorMessage) and handles the response as-expected once provided.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of Lambda Proxy Integration?

With this you don't need to do all those regular expression, as the whole request/response is parse to your lambda.

You control the status code by your lambda code instead of configuring the API Gateway.